# Is it possible to run 2 functions at the same time in PowerShell?

Tags: function, powershell

In a PowerShell script I have

```
function f1{ do something}
function f2{ do something else}
button1
button2
richtextbox
```

When I press `button1` it runs `f1` and it outputs data in the `richtextbox`.
When I press `button2` I need the script to run `f2` even if `f1` hasn't finished. The data from `f2` I don't need it to be outputted in the same `richtextbox`, it can be a different one.
My question is: can 2 different functions run at the same time in PowerShell?

Update:
For my PowerShell script I've done a GUI that has a bunch of button that do different things.
When I press one button it starts to connect to a serial device and outputs data to the richtextbox and at some points it saves data into a text file. 
2 other buttons have the following functions: it takes parts of data from the text file saved, opens a temporary php web server, opens a link to create a pdf file, and the it send the file to the correct printer/tray for printing.
These 2 buttons I've just noticed that they work.
My problem is with the buttons that are in a popup form.
One other button from my main form opens a popup form and populates it with data from the text file saved above.

```
$print_equip_button.Add_Click({
    print "link.php?data=$data" $file_location $type
}.GetNewClosure())
```

In the main form the code above works, from popup it doesn't.
Also tried with no luck.

```
$print_equip_button.Add_Click({
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock {print "link.php?data=$data" $file_location $type}
}.GetNewClosure())
```

I've added at the beginning of a function

```
for($i=1;$i -le 100;$i++){
    [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()
    start-sleep -s 1
    $LogTextBox.Text = "$temp`n" + "Count $i"
}
```

to see if what happens to function f1 when I press a button in the popup and from what I can see, when I open the popup form, the counting stops and continues when I close it.

UPDATE:
I found that if I have the script opened in PowerShell ISE and run it from there, everything works as I wanted without the need of "Start-Job".
When running the .ps file on its own it doesn't work, not even with "Start-Job"

Comment: Take a look at [Jobs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/4.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_jobs).

Comment: Tried with `Start-Job -ScriptBlock { function } with no luck

Answer (score 0):

Both jobs and runspaces will do this for you, remember though you have to specifically get the information back from the function, just running it in a different thread won't give you a return, as the output will be in a separate thread.

Jobs are better for a single function that takes a long time e.g deploying an ovf and runspaces are better for more broad functions e.g pinging 1000 machines in parallel.

You can use receive-job to get results back from start-job.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by asynchronous ui updation using runspaces:

```
  $button1_Click={

$ps = [powershell]::create()
$ps.AddScript(
     {
     #replace with your function definition
       while($true){
        $richtextbox1.appendtext("1")
        start-sleep 1
        }
    }
)

$ps.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("richtextbox1", $richtextbox1)
$ps.BeginInvoke()
}


$button2_Click={
$ps2 = [powershell]::create()
$ps2.AddScript(
     {
      #replace with your function definition
       while($true){
        $richtextbox2.appendtext("1")
        start-sleep 1
        }
    }
)


$ps2.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("richtextbox2", $richtextbox2)
$ps2.BeginInvoke()


    }
```